# Objective javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to apply objective approach in writing a very simple JS app but I cant seem to get it right...

There are several functions manipulating data in a table (in this example - highlighting rows with random colors after clicking on the link).

There is an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sa4ED/3/)

```
var MainFun = function() {}

MainFun.prototype.highlight = function(value) { 
       $(".conversationid")
          .filter(function() {
              return $(this).html() == value;
          })
          .css('background', 'transparent')
          .parent()
          .css('background', getRandomColor());
}


function getRandomColor() {
    return '#' + randHex() + "" + randHex() + "" + randHex();
}

function randHex() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 106) + 150).toString(16);
}

var f = new MainFun();
```

---

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="message">message1</td>
        <td class="conversationid">123</td>
        <td class="details"><a href="#"onclick="f.highlight('123');">click me</a></td>             
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="message">message2</td>
        <td class="conversationid">456</td>
        <td class="details"><a href="#"onclick="f.highlight('456');">click me</a></td>             
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="message">message3</td>
        <td class="conversationid">123</td>
        <td class="details"><a href="#"onclick="f.highlight('123');">click me</a></td>             
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="message">message4</td>
        <td class="conversationid">456</td>
        <td class="details"><a href="#"onclick="f.highlight('456');">click me</a></td>             
    </tr>
```

In this example, MainFun is the main objhect that should include all the functions (highlight, getRandomColor etc...)

I managed to made it work for the highlight function using prototype but when I try to do the same with the other functions, I get an error "f undefined". Could you suggest how to do it, please? Objective approach in JS seems to be quite different than in other languages... Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by 'objective' approach? Do you mean 'object oriented'?

Comment: What doesn't work - can you give us an example of what is not working?

Comment: Yes, I mean object oriented approach using prototypes... I am trying to rewrite this code to be fully object oriented...

Comment: SHOW what you tried that has the bug...Not what works...

Comment: `getRandomColor` and `randHex` are not registered under the `prototype` of `MainFun`. You declared them in the global scope.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sa4ED/4/ - this is my attemp but I know that this is not the proper way to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it like you did it with `highlight` function. And call the other prototype functions (also in highlight function) with `this`:

```
MainFun.prototype.getRandomColor = function() {
    return '#' + this.randHex() + "" + this.randHex() + "" + this.randHex();
}

MainFun.prototype.randHex = function() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 106) + 150).toString(16);
}
```

I've updated the fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sa4ED/7/)

Note the line:

```
var that = this;
```

It's because in the jquery closure scope the meaning of `this` will get changed.

Comment: I've seen that `var that = this;` is not necessary in this example because `getRandomColor` is not called from a closure. But you can keep in your head for the future ;)

Comment: Putting each function into a super main "class" has nothing to do with an "object oriented approach". Although it's hard to find any useful object oriented solution for such a simple example.

Comment: @hansmaad what do you mean? I don't see a module or similar pattern in all the examples on this page..

Answer (score 1):

I think this isn't a reasonable example to build a object oriented design. It's simple and should have a simple solution.

Anyway... putting each function into a super main "class" `MainFun` has nothing to do with an "object oriented approach". It's the same design like before. If you want to start with OOP you should think about responsibilities and create objects for them. In this example we could extract a `ColorPicker` from the MainFunc. And a `RandomColorPicker` could have a dependency to a random engine which is just a function returning a random hex.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sa4ED/10/)

```
var Main = function(colorPicker) {
    var that = this;
    this.colorPicker = colorPicker;  

    this.highlight = function(value) {
        $(".conversationid").filter(function() { 
            return $(this).html() == value; 
        })
        .css('background', 'transparent')
        .parent()
        .css('background', that.colorPicker.pickColor());
    };
};

var RandomColorPicker = function(randomEngine) {
    this.rand = randomEngine;
};

RandomColorPicker.prototype.pickColor = function() {
    return '#' + this.rand() + "" + this.rand() + "" + this.rand();
};

var randHex = function() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 106) + 150).toString(16);
};

var f = new Main(new RandomColorPicker(randHex));
```

Comment: You are right that the example is not the best to show object oriented design. Because there is no need for multiple instances an object literal approach would be better suited. But your `this.highlight` is a really bad design. It's a nested function inside a constructor function which will get copied everytime you create a new instance. Read about [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/stop-nesting-functions-but-not-all-of-them--net-22315).

Comment: @bitWorking Since there is always only one single instance, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, but this is no argument to justify bad design. If you write a library you never know how it will be used by others.

Comment: @bitWorking This is not a library. It's application code. And this is not design nor bad design. It is an implementation detail. This constructor func is only for injecting dependencies.